# "already covered” vs “has already been covered"

Tags: verbs

Let's say you are offering a *product* that is included in the benefit package from *Medicare* (a health insurance), what tense should you use?

> Promoter: Have no worries, this product **is already covered** by your Medicare, so it's free, you just have to agree.

Or

> Promoter: Have no worries, this product **has already been covered** by your Medicare, so it's free, you just have to agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"has already been covered"*** implies that it was covered in the past, and implies completion (the payment has gone through, the product purchased, etc). You would use this phrase if they were asking if their Medicare had completed payment for certain purchases in the past.

***"is already covered"*** implies that the product is *currently* covered by Medicare. That is, if they decided to purchase the product today, their Medicare would pay for it ("cover it"). The coverage is *ongoing*, and applies to present and future purchases.